# F-test of joint significance vs multiple t-test for regression parameters?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, t-test, least-squares, f-test

In the context of linear regression, I don't understand why you need to perform an F-test for the H0 that all parameters are zero, instead of just looking at all the t-tests for each parameter.

I understand that they are not the same, but I don't understand why. I sense that it has something to do with the covariance between the ols estimators (because the covariances are not used for the t-tests but all the estimated variance-covariance matrix is used for the F-test).

Answer (score 2):

The answer in one word: [multicollinearity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity). If two predictors are correlated it might happen that both is insignificant *itself* (i.e. with $t$-test), but they are jointly significant (with $F$-test). The reason is that multicollinearity will result in the variables mutually increasing each other's standard error, thus giving rise to the insignificance with $t$-test. Nevertheless, together they're significant. The very same works for more than two predictors (or all of the predictors) of course.

Comment: This looks like the best possible answer

Comment: This seems useful. Can I please check my understanding:

If an F-Test suggests the full model (aka all variables) is inadequate (as in, the f-statistic is less than the region of rejection), then that might be because two variables are significant but are highly correlated. Using VIF would reveal this multicolinearity.  A T-Test for each variable would check the significance of each variable, and we should find that both of the highly-correlated variables are significant.

Comment: To expand on that last comment: we should also be able to drop one of those highly-correlated variables, to adopt a simpler model, without a huge effect on the R-Squared for the model.

Comment: @ThreeDiag those comments were for you BTW

Comment: I think you got it the other way around. You might run a model and find that all your regressors show up as insignificant. At face value, this means there is little effect of the regressors on the dependent variable. But, the answer suggests, it could also be due to highly correlated regressors. The F test would reveal this by showing the opposite result, I. E. regressors are jointly significant. How to proceed then depends on the context, you might drop one variable or you might average the two variables together.